# how to set anchar for removing space between buttons

Tags: c#, button

I have some buttons that are inside of a panel, like the picture(1)
Its a user control.

I want that when somebody use my usercontrol, when resize the panel, the button size and the space of between them will change.

actually I want to have picture (3) but picture(2) will happend...

I set the anchar of panel, to right, left, top, botton. how to fix the buttons like picture 3?!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1 - Set 'MaximumSize' and 'MinimumSize' for all buttons in your user control.Something like this :

```
btnSave.MaximumSize = new Size(80, 30);
btnSave.MinimumSize = new Size(60, 30);
btnEdit.MaximumSize = new Size(80, 30);
btnEdit.MinimumSize = new Size(60, 30);
.
.
.
```

Or set from properties window.

2 - Set ' Anchor ' property for all buttons to Left,Right

3 - Write following code for 'Resize' event in your user control

```
private void UserControl1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lastLeft = 0 , lastWidth  = 0 ;
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            ctrl.Left = lastLeft + lastWidth + 3;
            lastLeft = ctrl.Left;
            lastWidth = ctrl.Width;
        }
    }
```

Note : Don't forget that you must cut the buttons from panel and paste them into user control.you don't need to panel and you can delete it.

Hope this be useful.

Comment: I updated my answer.It is better that lastLeft starts with 0.